# Read a string value from user and display its individuals charecters

Tags: java, string

**How to display individual characters of any String.** ***for example:***
 ***String str = "Java is one of the most popular language";***

output should be:  j,a,v,a   i,s     o,n,e   ....and so on.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class A 
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter any String:");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Before Splited: "+name);
        for(int i=0;i<name.length();i++){


            if(i>=0 || i<=name.length()){
                System.out.print(name.charAt(i));
                System.out.print(",");
            }
        }

    }
```

**is there any other approach instead of using if condition ?  please help me to solve it**  Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you feel it necessary to add the `if` condition at all?

Comment: Yeah, not using the `if` statement. It's always true, so just get rid of it. And since you never use `sname` and `newname`, get rid of those too.

Comment: already starting loop from 0 to name.length results if condition always true

Answer (score 1):

In your case you don't need the IF condition because the For loop iterates from 0 to your string length so `i` will ALWAYS be in that range and your if will ALWAYS be true. So just remove that.

More interesting question in your example is do you want that extra comma in the end of the string? Because currently if the string is 'test' you will receive 't,e,s,t,' which is kind of ugly.You can try to rework that instead

It's a good exercise for loops but you can also do it using the internal java libraries.

A fancy Java 8 example would be:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   String test="example";
   System.out.println(Stream.of(test.split("")).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have followed your solution to be to get you this results

**input**: `"Java is one of the most popular language"`

**output**: `"J,a,v,a i,s o,n,e o,f t,h,e m,o,s,t p,o,p,u,l,a,r l,a,n,g,u,a,g,e"`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A 
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name:");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Before Splited: "+name);
        String[] sname = str.split("");
        String joined1 = String.join(",", sname);
        joined1 = joined1.replace(" ,", " ").replace(", ", " ");
        System.out.println(joined1);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do not understand anything please let me know

Comment: But instead of  "J,a,v,a, i,s, o,n,e, o,f, t,h,e, m,o,s,t, p,o,p,u,l,a,r, l,a,n,g,u,a,g,e"   i want   "J,a,v,a  i,s  o,n,e  o,f  t,h,e  m,o,s,t  p,o,p,u,l,a,r l,a,n,g,u,a,g,e"   as output... Actually i want (,) only between each letters of a words  . for example "J,a,v,a  i,s"  instead of "J,a,v,a, i,s, ..."

Comment: I do not understand you quite well, so can you please clarify more

Comment: means i don't want comma (,) at the   end of last letter of each words like j,a,v,a,   should be  J,a,v,a   .    and i,s,  should be i,s  and so one..

Comment: My pleasure, anytime pal

Answer (score 1):

To have it formatted as your example (with commas only between letters), try this:

```
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter your name:");
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Before Splited: " + name);
            for(int i=0;i<name.length();i++){
                System.out.print(name.charAt(i));
                if((i+1)<name.length() && !name.charAt(i+1).equals(" "))
                     System.out.print(",");
            }
```

Input:

```
Java is one of the most popular languages
```

Output:

```
J,a,v,a i,s o,n,e o,f t,h,e m,o,s,t p,o,p,u,l,a,r l,a,n,g,u,a,g,e,s
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this-:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter your name:");
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Before Splited: " + name);
            for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
                System.out.print(name.charAt(i)+",");
            }
            sc.close();
        }
```

No need to add `if` condition.

Comment: It also splits surrogate pairs.

Answer (score -2):

What about this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(name.toCharArray()));
```

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(name.toCharArray()));
                               ^
  symbol:   variable Arrays
  location: class A

Comment: java.util.Arrays